# sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

Tags: sudo

I am facing some issues when i am trying to write sudo command.
Ex. If i run $ sudo -i command then i got -
This errors :
sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

Please help to solve this errors.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Error message is self explaining.
You should change permissions of /etc/sudoers, but root is needed for that so do from recovery mode:

```
chown root:root /etc/sudoers
chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers
```

Check content of file, make sure your username is there, so you allowed to use sudo. Thats all. `reboot`

Comment: Sorry.. I tried it but it's not working.

Comment: pkexec chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers   This command is solve this Problem.  :)